# How to create a list in Python with increment after 3 indexes and numpy.nan values in between

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I want to create a list having n number of elements and have increment of 1 after 3 indexes. For the elements in between, the values should by nan. Something like this:

```
[0, nan, nan, nan, 1, nan, nan, nan, 2, nan, nan, nan, 3, .....,]
```

I have tried using Numpy Arange method but can't make the logic.

Thanks

Comment: `[round(i/4) if i%4==0 else np.NaN for i in range(10)]` not a real answer, but  this is one way to do it.

Comment: Why this is not a real answer?! I think is the best one lol

Answer (score 1):

You can use [numpy.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html).

```
import numpy as np # import library

n=25 # array total length 
step = 4 # number of positions to skip minus one

condition = np.arange(0,n)%step==0 # array of booleans with lenght n and step 4 [true,false,false,false,true,false,false,false,true ...]
counter = np.cumsum(condition)-1 # array that counts [starting from zero] the number of true occurences in the array [0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,2 ...]
default_val = np.nan # default value of the output array

np.where(condition,counter,default_val) # returns the final array
```

You can also condense all the above code in one line using this statement:

```
np.where(np.arange(0,n)%step==0,np.cumsum(np.arange(0,n)%step==0)-1,np.nan)
```

python-3.x

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
n = 6
a = np.full(4 * n - 3, np.nan)
a[::4] = range(n)
print(a)

# [ 0. nan nan nan  1. nan nan nan  2. nan nan nan  3. nan nan nan  4. nan nan nan  5.]
```

or

```
n = 6
a = np.full(n, np.nan)
a[::4] = range(-(-n // 4))
print(a)
# [ 0. nan nan nan  1. nan]
```

if you know total number of elements in list.